# I need help with this inequality

Tags: inequality

$$
\frac{|x|}{(x + 2)|x - 5|} \le 0
$$

I thought to multiply the denominator to $0$, but I didn't think it is correct.

Comment: The function is continuous except at $-2,5$ where it's undefined, and has no sign change at $0$ since the factor is $|x|$ in the numerator. So it can only change sign at $-2$, since again no sign change at $5$ because of $|x-5|.$

Comment: You seem to have asked multiple questions regarding absolute values and should really should work towards an understanding how to solve problems involving absolute values instead of just asking about specific problems.

Answer (score 2):

Since the numerator is always positive, the only way the fraction can be smaller than zero is if the denominator is negative.

Because $|x-5|$ is always positive, the only way $(x+2)|x-5$| can be negative is if $(x+2)$ is negative, so $x<-2$.

You have to account for some things like denominator equaling $0$ but this should help you.